# How to replace the for each using streams in java

Tags: java, spring, foreach, java-8, java-stream

```
Dates.forEach(date -> {
            executeQuery(date, loads);
            
private void executeQuery(LocalDate date, ArrayList<Load> loads){
        MapSqlParameterSource source = new MapSqlParameterSource();
            source.addValue("date", date.toString());
            Load load = namedJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(Constants.SQL_QUERY, source,
                    new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Load.class));
            loads.add(load);
}
```

How can I use the streams concept for the above code

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```
// change your method like so            
private Load executeQuery(LocalDate date){
    MapSqlParameterSource source = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    source.addValue("date", date.toString());
    return namedJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(Constants.SQL_QUERY, source,
        new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Load.class));
}

// load your dates from somewhere
List<LocalDate> dates = getYourDates(); 
// now use the streams API to collect the query results into a new list
List<Load> loads = dates.stream()
  .map(this::executeQuery)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
List<Load> loads = getYourDates().stream()
  .map(this::executeQuery)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```